# How does m2eclipse artifact search work?

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse

Can someone explain the search function in m2eclipse? I am not clear on where this info is coming from and how to troubleshoot this when it can't find the artifact. I have two Eclipse installations, both with m2eclipse plugin, one works (find some artifacts not others) and the second one doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

When using maven from multiple eclipse installations, one method to get consistent results is to install maven separately and point eclipse (under Preferences->Maven->Installations) to the external maven instance in place of the embedded installation.  An additional advantage to this approach is the ability to run maven from the command line independent of IDE to get a 'pure' view of the build process.  This can be valuable when troubleshooting.

Regardless, m2eclipse uses the standard maven practice of locating a dependency in the local repository (typically {home directory}/.m2/repository), then turns to any 'remote' repositories.  The local repository location can be found in eclipse under Preferences->Maven->User Settings.  If no other configuration has been done, the 'central' maven repository at http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ is the next location searched.

Since you are getting different results from each of your eclipse installations, I would assume that they are looking at different repositories, although not certain how the settings would have gotten that way.  It would be interesting to know if the artifacts you are seeking are in the registered repository locations.

Note that this assumes you are accessing released artifacts.  If you are working with snapshots, the rules change a little and configuration (in settings.xml file) is significant.